How to open a Generated Code Coverage report in Intellij without re-running all tests?
If we click on Generate a code coverage report from Intellij, It will save a folder of HTML and some files in local at any specific location.
Now I can open the index page in any browser. But what if I want to see the report back in Intellij without rerunning all the test? Can I open this report from Intellij on same project?
Is there a way for this?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
